# Beautiful Soup: Extracting all the <br/> from the <strong>

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, dom-manipulation

I have a really silly and annoying problem, I try to convert html into markdown but my html is silly formatted: I keep having stuff like that:

```
<strong>Ihre Aufgaben:<br/></strong>
```

or

```
<strong> <br/>Über die XXXX GmbH:<br/></strong>
```

which is totally valid HTML.

However my library to convert to Markdown ([HTML2Text](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text)) converts it to:

```
**Ihre Aufgaben:\n**
```

and

```
** \nÜber die XXXX GmbH:\n**
```

which is an [already reported issue](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/issues/151) because **the markdown is then invalid and cannot be rendered properly**

My approach to this problem was the following:

- Use BeautifulSoup to find all the `strong` that lead to this problem
- Classify the `<br/>` into 2 groups: the ones coming before the text and the ones coming after the text.
- Unwrap the ones after the text in order to push them out of the `<strong>`

My code (not so great formatted yet):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
emphased = soup.find_all('strong')
for single in emphased:
    children = single.children
    before = 0
    foundText = None
    after = 0
    for child in children:
        if not isinstance(child, NavigableString):
             if foundText:
                after += 1
                child.unwrap()
             else:
                before += 1
                # DOES NOT WORK
                child.unwrap()
        else:
           foundText = single.get_text().strip()
```

**What is my current problem?**

I want to unwrap the `<br/>` **before** the content and put them **before** the `<strong>` element and I cannot achieve that (and didn't find how to proceed in the doc).

**What do I want to achieve more generally?**:

I want to transform that:

```
<strong> <br/>Über die XXXX GmbH: </strong>
```

into

```
# Note the space
(whitespace)<br/><strong>Über die XXXX GmbH:</strong>(whitespace)
```

It doesn't have to use Beautiful Soup, I'm just not aware of other solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your example you can extract all the `br` tags from the `strong` ones and prepend them, replacing the latest tag with the new one.

Here is a snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<strong>Ihre Aufgaben:<br/></strong>", "html.parser")
for strong in soup.find_all("strong"):
    [s.extract() for s in strong.find_all('br')]
    strong.string = strong.get_text(strip=True)
    strong.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup( " %s%s " % ("<br/>", strong), "html.parser"))
print soup
```

Which outputs:

`<br/><strong>Ihre Aufgaben:</strong>`

Comment: I don't think this solution takes the whitespace requirement into account, even though it should not be too hard to add it. (Perhaps even with a simple regex?)

Comment: My mistake - after extracting the `br` tags we can strip the text to get rid of that characters. Code updated;

Comment: Hey @Zroq, thanks for your time, I test it and come back to you :)

Comment: Ok guys, you helped me tremendously, I just solved my issue!